# VueJs add custom CSS provided from JSON

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am trying to add some custom CSS to my PWA Landingpage provided from REST JSON response. It looks like this: `{style: ".header{color: red}.footer{font-size:14px}"}`

is there any clean possibility make this in VueJs?

Comment: Yes this is possible in VueJS, you just need access to the DOM element (which you can get using document.querySelector for instance) and then set the style of the element using `element.setAttribute('style', response.style)`

Comment: You could also put `response.style` inside a new `<style>` element at the root of your element (`this.$el`) and insert the CSS rules that way (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)